# Does anybody know if this d3d9 debug output is bad?

Tags: c++, directx

The only d3d9 debug output i am receiving at the moment is
Direct3D9: :Window 000102b2 is on top of us!!

is this bad or is this standard output. I cant find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the output doesn't even have a severity printed with it (e.g., `(INFO)`, `(WARN)`, or `(ERROR)`), it's probably verbose output, i.e., not bad. You should be able to tweak the debug output level from the DirectX 9 control panel if you want to suppress it.

Comment: hmm i think you are right i do have it on maximum verbosity. thanks for the confirmation.

edit: yeah it went away went i changed it to level 4 from 5. thanks.